# Flash: which characters are allowed in instance names?

Tags: flash, naming-conventions, instance-variables

Flash tells me that instance names must contain "alphanumeric characters, supported symbols, and no whitespace". I've found the underscore is allowed, but not the minus sign.

Does anyone have a definitive list of all supported symbols?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting [Adobe Livedocs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/UsingFlash/help.html?content=WSd60f23110762d6b883b18f10cb1fe1af6-7c03.html)

> Instance names must conform to the
>   following requirements:
>
> - The name must not contain any spaces.
> - The first character must be a letter, underscore (_), or dollar sign
>     ($).
> - Each subsequent character must be a letter, number, underscore, or dollar
>     sign.
> - The instance name must be unique.

Answer (score 0):

i don't have such a list, but I suggest that you use camelCase for naming instances. Have the word start with a normal letter and whenever a new word starts, type the first letter of the word in a capital, like this: thisIsAnExample.

and i think only the underscore is allowed, since all the other signs are reserved for flash itself (-+*/% are for calculations, &|=!<> are for logic, . is for properties, so I guess that's most of the signs you would use in an instance-name).

edit: @ and \ are also reserved, so these signs can't be used aswell :)

Answer (score 0):

a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and _ should suffice to name any variable or instance you need to (I don't think you can start a name with a number though). Any other symbols would start to make your code unreadable.

For naming conventions, there are a lot you can chose from. The Wiki article gives good info on this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_conventions_(programming)